# mega drop down menu clashes with background picture

Tags: html, css

i have built a mega drop down menu

the problem is that it clashes with the background images and div on the main page

i have put a copy of my code on fiddle and would appriciate any advice on how to get around this: [mega Drop down menu](https://jsfiddle.net/TheSearcher/tfwL5erL/1/)

```
#menu {
    list-style:none;
    width:1100px;
    margin:30px auto 0px auto;
    height:43px;
    padding:0px 20px 0px 20px;

    background: #014464;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #0272a7, #013953);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#0272a7), to(#013953));


}

#menu li {
    float:left;
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
    position:relative;
    padding: 4px 10px 4px 10px;
    margin-right:30px;
    margin-top:7px;
    border:none;
    width: 7em;
}

.home-panel {
    color: #686767;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: "open-sans", "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
    line-height: 1;
    position: relative;
    cursor: default;
}

.home-panel {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("wallpaper.jpg") no-repeat scroll center center / cover;
    position: relative;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

[rachel gallen VERSION of mega drop](https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/tfwL5erL/2/)

hi everyone , rachel gallen has kindly shown me how to solve the problem with a Z-index.

only question that i have is that in rachel's version she does not have a gap in the drop down. my version has a gap. i was wondering how rachel did it-i obviously wish to replicate this.

**2nd UPDATE:**

the problem that i now encounter is a gap in the drop down.

[firstExample](https://jsfiddle.net/TheSearcher/vjewb3e8/)

i followed the recommendations of  @ThomasBaumgartner

> is caused by the fixed width of 7em in your #menu li declaration. if
>   possible remove "width: 7em" and add "white-space: nowrap" instead

[problems caused by removing width](https://jsfiddle.net/TheSearcher/v18zhj41/)

but this caused the blue background to push to the far left- it also made the home page dropdown menu to break out of its div

i would really appreciate any advice.

Comment: it moves to the left, because it has float:left.
it moves further to the left than before, because it's not stopped anymore by any bleeding menu item. Your fiddle doesnt work for me - css is missing.

Comment: margin-top:7px is causing the gap. remove it and work from there

Comment: hi Thomas i put the correct filddle under Probles caused by removing with.please click that link again;https://jsfiddle.net/TheSearcher/v18zhj41/

Comment: .home-panel .intro-signup {
    background-color: #034888;
    float: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 1px;
}
in case you want that sign-in form horizontally centered;
The padding-top prevents the headline margin from shifting dwon your box. anotherr way to accomplish this if you dont like the padding, is to set the headlines margin-top to 0.
https://jsfiddle.net/5su9uc4b/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a z-index property to your menu-fly-outs.

```
.dropdown_1column, 
.dropdown_2columns, 
.dropdown_3columns, 
.dropdown_4columns, 
.dropdown_5columns {
    ...
    z-index: 1; /* or higher, depending other layers you might use */
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I added `z-index:50;` into the following piece of code:

```
.dropdown_1column, 
.dropdown_2columns, 
.dropdown_3columns, 
.dropdown_4columns,
.dropdown_5columns {
    margin:4px auto;
    position:absolute;
    left:-999em; /* Hides the drop down */
    text-align:left;
    padding:10px 5px 10px 5px;
    border:1px solid #777777;
    border-top:none;
    z-index:50; 
    /* Gradient background */
    background:#F4F4F4;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #EEEEEE, #BBBBBB);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#EEEEEE), to(#BBBBBB));
```

Et voila!

Comment: hello Rachel. thank you so much for this. is it appropriate to add Z-index to divs. i thought that z-index only referred to the stacking order of images

Comment: no it refers to the order in which you want thing s to appear on the page so applying it to divs is fine

Comment: @Paul: z-index applies to all positioned elements (absolute/srelative/fixed)
BTW: in your example you need that only because the relative positioned elements in the home panel

Comment: hey Rachel and everyone. i understand now. quick question everyone. When i click the dropdown for find childcare there is a gap in the dropdown  .  i am confused what is causing this

Comment: sorry. i meant in my drop down. not rachels. i am trying to work out how Rachel stopped the gap from appearing

Comment: @Paul: it is caused by a line break in this menu item, mabe add white-space: nowrap;

Comment: I'm using Firefox, I can see that gap also in Rachel's jsfiddle.
the gap is caused by the line break which in rteur is caused by the fixed width of 7em in your #menu li declaration. if possible remove "width: 7em" and add "white-space: nowrap" instead.

Comment: hey @ThomasBaumgartner i tried your solution but although it works, it creates other problems. i have added an update along with the jfiddle . would love your help